# How to make parameters look more attractive

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm making a blog site and instead of the users blogs being called /blog?display=*username* I would like it to just be a sub domain such as mysite.com/*username*

How would I be able to make the first URL look like the second URL?

Comment: Er... That's not a subdomain. A subdomain would be `username.mysite.com`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog?display=$1 [L]
```

This will redirect each URL which do not corresponds to an existing file (`!-f`) or existing directory (`!-d`) to the corresponding `blog?...` URL. `[L]` makes the rewriting stop here (in case you have more rules). See the [mod_rewrite Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/) for details.

Comment: Thanks that looks really helpful, Thanks would you be able to explain what the symbols mean so ill be able to edit this as I want?

Comment: @Joel: Have a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/ (and some of the pages linked from there).

Comment: Another resource which may be useful: [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-ask)

Comment: @zgold: Thanks very much for the help. The exact URL I am trying to get is joelhoskin.net76.net/blogs/theblogsnamehere to joelhoskin.net76.net/blogs/blog?display=theblogsnamehere

I've put this in the .ht access file which doesn't seem to be working
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^joelhoskin.net76.net/blogs/(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.joelhoskin.net76.net/blogs/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.joelhoskin.net76.net/blogs/blog?display=$1 [L]

Sorry this comment seemed to remove my link break, should I start a new question?

Comment: Realized I missed off .php from the rewrite rule, still doesnt work though

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for mod_rewrite. It's easy, just put this in your `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog?display=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PATH_INFO variable.  More here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html

Previous answer (using Request.PathInfo) was tarted at asp.net -- thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: ASP.NET is not really applicable on Apache, is it?