# Mod Rewrite not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get the URL `www.example.com/blogs/<displaynamehere>` to show what is in the directory at
 `www.example.com/blogs/blog.php$display=<displaynamehere>`

So thanks to the people who helped me here I know I need to use mod_rewrite
[How to make parameters look more attractive](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/17304/how-to-make-parameters-look-more-attractive)

The contents of my .htaccess is as follows. The first is a redirect generated by my hosting, the second is my attempt at the mod_rewrite which is not working.

```
# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES BELOW REDIRECTID:Hjz5g3
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^joelhoskin.net76.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.joelhoskin.net76.net$
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.joelhoskin.net76.net/flexdevs [R=301,L]
# DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE AND THE LINES ABOVE Hjz5g3:REDIRECTID

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^joelhoskin.net76.net/blogs/(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.joelhoskin.net76.net/blogs/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.joelhoskin.net76.net/blogs/blog.php?display=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The host shouldn't contain anything after the slash. So you want:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^joelhoskin.net76.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.joelhoskin.net76.net$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blogs\/(.*)$ http://www.joelhoskin.net76.net/blogs/blog.php?display=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help it worked a treat it did re-direct however chrome gave me this error

Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.

Firefox throws
"Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

Comment: Actually it seems to have that error on the enter /blogs directory

Comment: http://www.joelhoskin.net76.net/blogs/blog.php?display=blog.php
Every page just redirects here, however I have a redirect in the blog.php that if the display doesnt exist it redirects back to the blogs/index.php and since that page redirects to the previous one its caught in a loop

Comment: @paulmorriss There is no need to escape slash `/` character at all.

Comment: Ok I removed all escape slashes and now the entire site just 404s

Comment: Whoops! I didn't spot that. I've now amended with an extra line to exclude blog.php. LazyOne, cPanel puts them in so I tend to do it. I've taken them out on the right hand side.

Comment: It's still doing the same thing sorry, I don't think its taking the right variable, its just copying blog.php rather than what you write in. I don't know how to fix it though.

Comment: Also as a side how will I be able to add exceptions for each of my pages. For example blogs/index.php is my index page rather than a blog called index

Comment: I've taken a couple of lines from the top answer to your other question to handle those cases. That should also solve the problem with my second version not working. (It should have been RewriteCond ${PATH_INFO} !=blogs/blog.php in fact, but those lines handle make sure all php files don't get redirected.)

Comment: It works perfect now, thanks very much for your help :P

Comment: @paulmorriss It takes you to the correct profile now but how do I change the setting so instead of showing the full URL the browser just keeps showing the url used to access the page. I was reading about it in the apache docs. I tried to add [PT] but that resulted in 404's

Comment: By specifying an absolute URL (protocol + domain) in the `RewriteRule` _substitution_, it will implicitly trigger an external redirect (so the URL will change) even though the `R` flag is not present. For an _internal rewrite_ the substitution should simply be `blogs/blog.php?display=$1`.